# Program to read a code and count the number of lines in it,do not include comments and blank lines in count

Tags: c, whitespace, line-count

I am trying to create a program which, given an input file, returns the count of all the lines of code in the input file, excluding blank lines and comment lines. I have written the following code, however I need help with how to exclude lines containing comments and blank lines.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int count;
    char ch;
    FILE *fptr;
    clrscr();
    fp=fopen("test.cpp","r");
    if(fp==EOF)
        {
        perror("Error:");
        }
    else
    {
        while(ch!=EOF)
        {
            ch=fgetc(fptr);
            if(ch=='\n')
                count++;
            if(ch=='\\')
                count--;
            if(ch=='\*')
                          {
                while(ch!='*\')
                                    {
                    ch=fgetc(fptr);
                                    }
            }
        }
    printf("the lines in the code are %d\n",count);
    fclose (fptr)
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I modify the above code so that blank lines and comment lines are not counted?

Comment: Exactly how is it "not working"?

Comment: How can I modify the above code so that blank lines and comment lines are not counted?

Comment: uninitialized `ch`. It may happen your program never even enters the while loop.

Comment: I guess ch can contain anything garbage rather than EOF or can EOF also be assigned as garbage?

Comment: if `ch` is signed, garbage can be EOF. Anyway ... `ch` should be `int` **and initialized** -- or redo the whole program :-)

Comment: The question *still* stands as *"Here a big block of code I want fixed. Do it for me."* which is *still* not a real question. When the OP is prepared to state what he does not get, we'll be getting somewhere...until then this *should* be closed.

Comment: This is a great comment according to me so vote up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the input file character by character, you'll have a lot more work than if you read it line by line. After all you're counting lines ...

psudocode

```
    1. initialize line count to 0
    2. read a line
    3. end of file? yes: goto 7
    4. is it a good line? yes: goto 5; no: goto 2
    5. increment line count
    6. repeat from 2
    7. output line count
```

Now you ask ... what is a good line?
For an approximation of the program, I suggest you consider a line everything except lines composed of 0 or more whitespace. This approximation will count comments, but you can develop your program from here.

The following version ignores lines with // coments on an otherwise empty line.

Version 3 could ignore lines containing both `/*` and `*/`

and version 4 would deal with multi line comments.

**Above all, have fun!**

Answer (score 2):

C comments are `//` and `/* */`.  The following lines are where your problem is:

```
        if(ch=='\\')
            count--;
        if(ch=='\*')
            while(ch!='*\')
                ch=fgetc(fptr);
```

The other problem is that you can't match a two-character comment delimiter by reading a character at a time without some sort of state machine.

Also, your code should cater for the case where comments are embedded in real lines of code.  eg.

```
x = 1;    // Set value of x
```

You'd be far better off reading the file a line at a time, and checking whether or not each line is blank or a comment, and incrementing a counter if not.

Comment: what should I do for the comments?Any hint ?and how do I deal with the blank lines?

Comment: I'd be reading each line, stripping leading and trailing white-space, then determining if the string is empty, is a comment, or is real code.

Comment: Ignore them.  A line of C code can contain embedded comments, or a // comment at the end, but should be counted as code.

Answer (score 1):

you mean //, /* and */ instead of \ * and *\

the \ is used as an escape character, which changes the "meaning" of the character after it.

\n gives you a newline. with `\\` you get a single \ and with \' you get something that doesn't close the opening '

If you replace those comment-characters with the correct one you should  get code that will compile.
But it wont count correctly.

Imagine a line like this:

```
doSomething(); // foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your problems with character constants you have errors in the way you deal with `fputc`. `fputc` returns an `int`. It can return either `EOF` which is a negative integer constant if there were no remaining characters to red or there was an error, or it can return the value of the character read as an `unsigned char` and converted to a `int`.

If you convert the return value of `fputc` to `char` before comparing it to `EOF` then a valid character might compare as equal to `EOF` causing premature termination of your loop.

Also, not that the `while` loop starts before the first call to `fputc` so you are using the uninitialized value of `ch` in the first iteration. This could cause anything to happen.

The idiomatic way to form the loop would be:

```
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc()) != EOF)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

In side the loop you need to be careful in the comparison of the returned value due to the way the fact that `ch` is the `unsigned char` converted to an `int`.

On most platforms the simplest thing to do would be to create a char variable for comparison purposes although you could put your character constants throught the same `unsigned char` to `int` conversion routine.

E.g.

```
char c = ch;

if (c == '\n')
```

or

```
if (ch == (unsigned char)'\n')
```

Others have pointed out the problems with your character literals.

Answer (score 0):

Well, part of the problem is that your ch variable is only a character in length, but when you test for comments, such as `\\` and `\*`, these are two characters long, and thus need to use string comparison.

Another problem is that one-line comments in C/C++ actually start with `//`, and multi-line comments start with `/*` and end with `*/`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this in Python:

```
def goodline(l : str) -> int:
    if l.lstrip().startswith("/*") and l.rstrip().endswith("*/"):
        # single line
        return 0
    elif l.lstrip().startswith("/*") and not l.rstrip().endswith("*/"):
        # multi line start
        return 1
    elif not l.lstrip().startswith("/*") and l.rstrip().endswith("*/"):
        # multi line end
        return 2
    elif l.strip() == "":
        # empty line
        return 3
    elif l.lstrip().startswith("//"):
        # single line
        return 0
    else:
        # good line
        return 4
```

if return from above function is 1, keep iterating on lines until return becomes 2.